# How to prioritise operators

Tags: java, calculator

I am creating a Calculator with + - * / and %(Modulus). The basic calculator is working but I am now wondering how I should prioritise multiplication and division before addition and substraction. Can't really figure it out.

I need to write a whole string which will be converted to a double and then back to string for printout.

example: 3+3-4*8+5/6+5

Here is my code below

```
public String calculateExpression(String expression){
    double dres = 0.0;
    String[] split = expression.split("(?=[*/+-])|(?<=[*/+-])");
    dres = Double.parseDouble(split[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < split.length; i+= 2) {
        String op = split[i];
        double val = Double.parseDouble(split[i+1]);
        switch (op) {
        case "+":
                dres = Addition(dres, val);
            break;
        case "-":
                dres = Subtraction(dres, val);
            break;
        case "*":
                dres = Multiplication(dres, val);
            break;
        case "/":
                dres = Division(dres, val);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    String res = Double.toString(dres);
    return res;
}

public double Addition(double d1,double d2) {
    return d1+d2;

}

public double Subtraction(double d1, double d2) {
    return d1-d2;
}

public double Multiplication(double d1, double d2) {
    return d1*d2;
}

public double Division(double d1, double d2) {
    return d1/d2;
}

public double Modulus(double d1, double d2) {
    return d1%d2;
}
```

Comment: Please read: [Recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is scan for the right-most occurrence of a * or /, and split the `String` into two parts (to the left of the symbol and to the right of the symbol). Then, call your own method to determine the values of either side; then perform the multiplication/division operation.

If there isn't any * or /, you can do the same thing for + and -.

If there isn't any operator at all, then just return the number.

Comment: For this, you'll want to refactor your method so that it returns a `double`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like a brute force approach:

```
public String calculateExpression(String expression){
double dres = 0.0;
String[] split = expression.split("(?=[*/+-])|(?<=[*/+-])");
dres = Double.parseDouble(split[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < split.length; i+= 2) {
    String op = split[i];
    double val = Double.parseDouble(split[i+1]);
    switch (op) {
        if(case == "+" or case == "*") {
            case "+":
                dres = Addition(dres, val);
            break;
            case "*":
                dres = Multiplication(dres, val);
            break;
        }
        else {
            case "-":
                dres = Subtraction(dres, val);
            break;
            case "/":
                dres = Division(dres, val);
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
String res = Double.toString(dres);
return res;   }
```

Not sure if the code is correct, but you get the gist.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic application of the [Interpreter Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern).

Unfortunately, I had trouble understanding what exactly the example on wikipedia is doing...

But the solution definitely has to do with stacks (called `ArrayDeque` in Java).

Comment: You can do it with stacks, yes. I suggest using recursion however as it avoids a lot of boilerplate code.